# Superflous vertical spacing after tagging environment

Tags: spacing, environments

I would like to use the `tagging` package to tag parts of a document, which not only contain text, but also other environments like `enumerate`. If I use the `taggedblock`-environment for this, this creates additional vertical space after the `taggedblock`, see the minimal example below. Is there any way to avoid that? This effectively ruins the layout of my document. :/

One solution would be to replace the `taggedblock`-environment by the `\tagged`-command, but I don't want to do that, since the parts of the documents are quite large and every time I forget a `}` to close the `\tagged`-command it becomes a mess.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tagging}

\usetag{mytag}

\begin{document}

%a tagged block
\begin{taggedblock}{mytag}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    foo
    \item
    bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{taggedblock}
%here you have additional vertical space
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    foo
    \item
    bar
\end{enumerate}
%here you don't 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    foo
    \item
    bar
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For strange reasons, the `taggedblock` environment adds `\leavevmode` at the end, which is clearly wrong.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tagging}
\def\endtaggedblock{\endcomment} % we can't use \renewcommand

\usetag{mytag}

\begin{document}

%a tagged block
\begin{taggedblock}{mytag}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    foo
    \item
    bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{taggedblock}
% normal spacing
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    foo
    \item
    bar
\end{enumerate}
% normal spacing
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    foo
    \item
    bar
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "I'm pretty sure there was a reason for the `\leavevmode` at the time, but the margin of my memory is too small to contain it."

Comment: @Brent.Longborough LOL :) :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a clarificatory answer; as the person who "caused the problem in the first place", I don't expect upvotes (nor, hopefully, downvotes)

I am in the process of deprecating the `tagged` package; [Boris Veytsman's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522/boris) [`multiaudience`](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/multiaudience/multiaudience.pdf) package is much better thought-out, and Boris is a much better TeXnician than I am.

Here's your original problem, rewritten to use `multiaudience`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multiaudience}

\SetNewAudience{mytag}
\DefCurrentAudience{mytag}

\begin{document}

%a tagged block
\begin{shownto}{mytag}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    foo
    \item
    bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{shownto}
%here you have additional vertical space
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    foo
    \item
    bar
\end{enumerate}
%here you don't 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    foo
    \item
    bar
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You deserve an upvote, also for _the person who "caused the problem in the first place"_ !

Answer (score 0):

Just for others which have a similar problem...the `tagged` command doesn't cause the problem.

The `taggedblock` blocks also cause problem when using before `part` and `chapter` commands. I get **unwanted empty pages**.

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a5,
    fontsize=12,
    ]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tagging}

\usetag{myTag-A}
\usetag{myTag-B}

\droptag{myTag-A}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{taggedblock}{myTag-A}
\part{Test Part A}
\end{taggedblock}

\begin{taggedblock}{myTag-B}
\part{Test Par B}
\end{taggedblock}

\end{document}
```

I don't have this problem with the `tagged` command:

```
\tagged{myTag-A}{
\part{Test Part A}
}

\tagged{myTag-B}{
\part{Test Par B}
}
```